# ID Token from OpenId Connect

Tags: single-sign-on, jwt, security-token, open-id-connect

We are using OpenId Connect for SSO into a Community with an external Identity Provider. It is easy to get the Access Token returned via AuthToken.getAccessToken.
Is there any way get the ID Token (JWT)?

Use Case: There is an API we need to call from Salesforce that requires both the Access Token and ID Token that is returned via OpenId Connect SSO.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What's the use case here? What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The id token is intended for consumption by the relying party, that would be Saleforce platform in this case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkPond - There is a separate system we need to communicate with from Salesforce once the user is logged in that requires the ID Token.

Comment: @identigral - thanks, I have updated the details to include the Use Case of why we need it.